# dateutil.relativedelta handles years incorrectly

Tags: python-dateutil, python-relativedelta

There's something wrong with adding years:

```py
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

if __name__ == '__main__':
    date = datetime.today().date()
    print(date)
    print(date + relativedelta(year=1))

### 2022-07-27
### 0001-07-27 – why!?
```

Could anyone explain that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are having is that `year` (singular) *sets the year* of whatever it is added to, whereas `years` (plural) represents an offset in years. See [the documentation](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html#module-dateutil.relativedelta), which has a whole section on the difference.